# Error al usar encabezado con laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola** estoy importando datos de un archivo `excel` y estoy tratando de usar una fila de encabezado pero al momento de hacer el `import` me sale el siguiente error:

```
Use of undefined constant TipoInstrumento - assumed  'TipoInstrumento' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

El metodo de como estoy importando es el siguiente:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    //Si no encuentra el dato en la tabla lo crea

    $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate(
        ['tipo_nombre' => $row[TipoInstrumento]],//busca
        ['tipo_nombre'=>$row[TipoInstrumento]] //crea
    );
    $marca = tbl_marca::firstOrCreate(
        ['mar_nombre' => $row[Marca]],
        ['mar_nombre'=>$row[Marca]]
    );

    $id = Auth::id(); //trae el id del usuario logeado

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[Codigo],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[ObservacionInicial],
        'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$row[ProximaCalibracion],
        'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>$row[UltimaCalibracion],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[ClaseOExactitud],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row[Nserie],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row[DivOEscala],
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row[ConsecutivoInterno],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row[Observaciones],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row[ObservacionFinal],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row[Magnitud],
        'ins_modelo' => $row[Modelo],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row[CodigoActividad],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);
}
```

La celda que estoy pasando el `TipoInstrumento`ya verifique que es la misma, no entiendo porque me sale el error antes no me estaba molestando, como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Pon el índice entre comillas `$row['TipoInstrumento']`

Comment: `Undefined index: TipoInstrumento` al ponerlo en comillas me sale lo siguiente

Comment: Implementaste `WithHeadingRow`? Que valores tienen las celdas del encabezado? El encabezado está en la primer fila?

Comment: Si, el encabezado esta en la primera fila y los valores estan tal cual, pude solucionarlo poniendo comillas y sin mayusculas, Pero tengo un problema ahora con el `first or create` de nuevo es raro